# How can I sum up 3 columns specifically using pandas for below data & create new column to flag if it's greater than 0 or equal to 0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**For the below data I want to create columns, if the sum of A+B+C = 0 then I want to flag 'NoCommit'
and if it is greater than 0 I want to flag 'Commit'**

```
revno       author      msg                                        A    B   C

3030        rohit       modified                                   0    1   0
3031        rohit       Statistical Report changes Done            0    2   0
3032        sandeep     OTPIntegration flow changed                0    0   0
3033        sandeep     Captcha code Integration Done.             0    0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with `sum`:

```
df['new'] = np.where(df[['A','B','C']].sum(axis=1).eq(0),'NoCommit','Commit')
```

Or:

```
df['new'] = np.where((df.A + df.B + df.C).eq(0),'NoCommit','Commit')
```

EDIT:

If columns are not numeric, use:

```
df['new'] = np.where(df[['A','B','C']].astype(float).sum(axis=1).eq(0),'NoCommit','Commit')
```

Comment: @Aditya - Not understand, there is not selected `new`

Comment: sorry? how can I fix it?

Comment: @Aditya - Not understand, `new` is existed column?

Comment: @Aditya - So if created how possible error `KeyError: 'new'` ? This error is if need select column. Weird.

Comment: I made the code work, but it's not working, Getting the same flag for both the condition.

Comment: @Aditya - So need `df['new'] = np.where(df[['A','B','C']].astype(float).sum(axis=1).eq(0),'NoCommit','Commit')` ?

Comment: Columns are numeric,the data type is int64

Comment: @Aditya - So `print (df[['A','B','C']].sum(axis=1))` working correct? Or all data are `0` ?

Comment: all the three columns are not summing up, instead in A column if the value is above 0 then it flagging differently.

Comment: @Aditya - `all the three columns are not summing up` - unfortunately not understand, `instead in A column if the value is above 0` what it means?

Comment: If A column has greater than 0 then only it's giving 'Commit' Flag. But if A column has 0 value and Other two columns, B and C has values greater than 0 then it's not giving 'Commit ' Flag

Comment: Leave it, I managed to get the output using other method. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Aditya - What is `print(df[['A','B','C']].dtypes)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Naive Approach:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C']
df['Commit'] = df['NoCommit'] = None
df.loc[:,['Commit', 'NoCommit']] = \
              [ (1,0) if i > 0 else (0,1) for i in df[['A','B','C']].sum(axis=1)]
```